# Approval Workflow (OOB 2010) vs. Version Control hiding documents

Tags: workflow, approval, online, version

We have implemented the out of box SP 2010 approval workflow for a sharepoint library. We have also enabled version control so that unapproved documents don't appear to the 'average user'.
The problem is:

When a document is uploaded, it starts the approval workflow process. 
The process won't start until the document is "checked in" after upload. Then, the document has to be approved (per SP version control settings).

If a user uploads a document, they have to check in, THEN they have to right-click the document to 'approve' it in the library.  Each time, the workflow is started...so we get 2 workflow approvals for a single document upload.

Anyone have a better way to use a multi-person approval but still hide unapproved versions?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 - Designer Workflow on a document library, we have an action named "`Wait for Document to be Check in`" use this action as your first step and then have your approval task action, so when a user uploads a document, the workflow will wait for the document to be checked-in, then once the user checks-in the document, then the approval task will be created to the users.

Comment: Thanks, Karthik.
This already happens. When the user checks in, the workflow starts.
Then, it has to be 'approved' in the library to be visible to anyone...this starts the workflow again.
I'm using the out of box workflow, so I can't modify it. I have downloaded SP Designer, but I've done nothing with it so far.

Comment: ok then, goto your workflow configuration page and uncheck the "Changing an item will start this workflow.", so once approved, this will not again start the workflow. So, workflow will start only once on item create.

Comment: Did this help you??

Comment: Sadly no.  I don't want to enable document changes without approval. I am trying to use a Sharepoint library for a document control solution...wherein I need to control who changes a document, and that changes are reviewed prior to publishing.
I can confirm that the approval Flow doesn't start again with this setting disabled, but I also confirmed that I can change the document and nobody would know.  That goes against the intent of the approval implementation.

Comment: What I'm experiencing here is summarized as such:

The workflow automates the task of approving...separate from the library approval settings.
The document must be checked in and approved before being visible to users. These settings, however, have nothing to do with the Workflow for approval. The Flow runs parallel (and disconnected) from library approval and checkin.
I only want to show approved documents to users.